# How do we define "volume" of the gas undergoing free expansion in vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Usually volume occupied by the gas is defined as the the volume of the container, but as it expands freely (Joule's free expansion), we can't say anything about volume in a concrete sense as we don't have a **rigid container**. How do we think about this in a more concrete way?

Comment: We would first need the criterium what is a gas and what is vacuum.

Comment: What about $V \to \infty$?

Comment: I often see people talking about expansions in a vacuum , how do they do this without something to concretely call volume?

Comment: Particularly, it is undefined.